# want to convert a ternary operator into a loop

Tags: pine-script

I’m making an indicator where I only want to save the value of the `high[100]` if the 99 candelse after that are less than the `high[100]`.

I want to keep that value until I get another condition like that one, it does not matter if the last `high[100]` is higher or lower than the new `high[100]` condition.

I tried doing it in a loop but because I'm very new to loops I have not yet succeeded.

```
 //@version=3
strategy("trend hybrid",overlay=true)

long_2 = highest(high,100)
high_long = high[100]
long_test = highest(high,99)

long = na
long := long_test <= high_long ? high_long : long[1]

plot(long) 


//@version=3
study("For Loop tutorial - Example 6")
l = high[100]
y = high
for i = 99 to 1
    if high[i] <= high[l]
        break    
    y := l

plot(y, style=line, color=green, linewidth=3)
```

Comment: Hi your question is not clear and you might get downvotes. To clarify, the condition you want is

you want to set the `high[100]` to a certain variable if the last 101 - 200 candles are less than that `high[100]` 

is this what u mean?

Comment: your richt oke i have updated the code i want to convert that code in a loop. so i want to get the same result, but then in a form of a loop

Comment: So where are you having your problem? There is no attempt in your code that tries what you described (no loop or whatsoever).

Comment: the second script is what i have tried

Comment: but im verry new to loops and i dont realy know what im doing

Comment: so i realy hoop you guys can help me

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for. Remember it takes 100 bars to detect your condition, so the blue label and line are printed with an offset of your `length - 1` in the past. Only the fuchsia circle which appears when a new high is detected is plotted on the candle where detection occurs. You can change the length in the *Inputs*.

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
length = input(100)
highBar = -highestbars(length) == length - 1
var highValue = 0.
if highBar
    highValue := high[length - 1]
    label.new(bar_index[length - 1], highValue, tostring(highValue), xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, size = size.normal)
plot(highValue, "highValue", offset = -(length - 1))
plotchar(highBar, "High detected", "•", location.abovebar, color.fuchsia, size = size.small)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Luc, your code scans for the highes bar in 100 and if its the last one it shows that. This is not what he is asking for.

Comment: Y, could very well be it's not. Wasn't too sure my code was what he wanted, so figured I'd show something and comments or other answers would follow. Maybe you got it right.

Answer (score 0):

Am gonna walk you through the 2 ways to do it, using the loop since that's what you want, and using the recommended way.

**Using Loops**

```
//@version=4
//@author=lucemanb
study("Highest", overlay=true)

// your bars limit
limit = input(100)

// we start comparing from 100th bar to the next 100 candles
highest = high[limit]

// if we find a candle greater than that, we set the high to the new value
//for i=limit to limit+limit // refer bottom 11
for i=0 to limit
    if high[i] > highest
        highest := high[i]

// we check - if our 100th high is equal to the highest value that we were searching for, it means its the highest.
newValue = high[limit] == highest

// we draw a background color on the place that we find
// note that, since we are checking the level 100 candles behind, we need to set the offset so
// that we can see where the level is
bgcolor(newValue?color.red:na, offset=-limit)

// 11 Your after is ambiguous, if you mean the candles older than 100th candle, remove the first '//' on line 12 and put it on lime 13
```

**Recommended way**

```
//@version=4
//@author=lucemanb
study("Highest", overlay=true)

// your bars limit
limit = input(100)

// we simply check if our 100th high is equal to the highest high 
// from the 100th candle to the other 99 candles after it.
newValue = high[limit] == highest(limit) //[limit] // refer bottom 11

// we draw a background color on the place that we find
// note that, since we are checking the level 100 candles behind, we need to set the offset so
// that we can see where the level is
bgcolor(newValue?color.red:na, offset=-limit)

// 11 Your after is ambiguos, if you mean the candles older than 100th candle, remove the first '//' on the line 10
```

Please do go throught the comments

---

I hope this helps

Comment: @lucaalbers does it help?

Comment: yes it does i have one more Question. if you can help me i would really apriciate it

Comment: this is the title . if you look at my acc you can find it.trying to have a stop and a limit strategy.exit